# STDIN breaks my select list

Tags: bash, select

I have a script that can optionally take some input on STDIN and later presents the user with a few select lists.  When data is input on STDIN the select list presents but exits without taking input, however it works fine when nothing is provided via stdin.

I have a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -p /dev/stdin && ${#bar[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r foo; do
        bar+=("$foo")
    done </dev/stdin
fi

for foo in "${bar[@]}"; do
    echo "$foo"
done

select thing in foo bar baz; do
    case $thing in
        *)  echo "You have selected $thing"; break;;
    esac
done
```

Executing without stdin:

```
$ ./script.sh
1) foo
2) bar
3) baz
#? 2
You have selected bar
```

Executing with stdin:

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar | ./script.sh
foo
bar
1) foo
2) bar
3) baz
#?
$
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've "used up" all of *stdin* by the time the `select` is executed, so it returns with status 1 and nothing selected

Perhaps you were wanting to force interactivity by reading from `/dev/tty`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    while IFS= read -r foo; do
        bar+=("$foo")
    done
fi

for foo in "${bar[@]}"; do
    echo "$foo"
done

select thing in foo bar baz; do
    case $thing in
        *)  echo "You have selected $thing"; break;;
    esac
done </dev/tty
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work when stdin is piped but seems to break when there is no STDIN

Comment: It breaks in what way?

Comment: It never brings up the select list, it just sits there waiting for me to input stdin.

Comment: I don't see that in my testing

Comment: I see, it requires I remove the pointless redirect from </dev/stdin on my read loop.

Comment: Suggest you change the `-p /dev/stdin` too so it works with file redirection as well as pipes